# Semi-simplicity of the representation after extension from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $\Gamma$ be a finitely generated group and let $\rho:\Gamma\to GL_n(\mathbb{Q})$ be a semi-simple representation.

Question: is the induced representation $\rho':\Gamma\to GL_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ semi-simple?

Comment: No, why should it?

Comment: No, there are plenty of counterexamples with $\Gamma$ cyclic (using a polynomial that is irreducible over $\mathbf{Q}$ but not over $\mathbf{Q}_p$).

Comment: @ YCor: is the reductivity preserved after the extension?

Comment: By the remarks of @Ycor, irreducibility is not preserved. I changed the question for semi-simplicity.

Comment: Semi-simplicity is preserved under extensions (in characteristic 0).

Comment: semisimplicity means that the subalgebra generated by the group is semisimple, and this is indeed stable under taking extensions, in char 0.

Comment: @YCor Thanks! Could you provide a reference please?

Comment: A thorough covering of semisimplicity of algebras, taking into account issues of non-perfect fields, is in the 2012 edition of Bourbaki, Algebra, Chap. 8. But for char 0 most standard books do the job, e.g., Pierce, Associative algebras.

Comment: Look for the buzz word separable algebra over a field.